# Comparison of ratios between multiple groups

Tags: group-differences

I need to perform statistical analysis whether there is any difference in the usage of each gene version between disease groups. I have 3 groups, in each group there is a different no. of patients. For each patient I have a different no. of sequencing reads (100%), from which I identified usage of each gene version for each patient.
E.g.

Disease A
Patient 1   Total: 19402, version1: 492, version2: 45, version3: 3201, version 4: 15664
Patient 2   Total: 143, version1: 34, version2: 4, version3: 15, version4: 90
Patient 3 etc

Disease B
Patient 1
Patient 2
Patient 3
Patient 4

Disease C
Patient 1
Patient 2
Patient 3

etc.

There is a big difference in the total number of reads yielded per each patient from which I am identifying gene versions. What type of analysis would you recommend I carry out? I hope my explanation makes sense. I am a complete beginner in stats and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to determine. Do you want to compare versions in different diseases? For example, version4 may be commoner in disease A and version 2 in disease B?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare usage of each version between disease groups to determine whether there are any significant differences :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a contingency table as follows:

```
  dss    1    2    3    4
1   A 1250 1833 1166 1792
2   B 2788 2396 1307 3024
3   C  828 1626 1741 2052
4   D 1271 2617  929 1505
```

Here each value is sum of all patients for that particular disease and version. Row and column percentages can be calculated (row and column sums are also shown here):

```
     [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5]
[1,] 20.7  30.3 19.3  29.7  100
[2,] 29.3  25.2 13.7  31.8  100
[3,] 13.3  26.0 27.9  32.8  100
[4,] 20.1  41.4 14.7  23.8  100
[5,] 83.4 122.9 75.6 118.1  400
> 
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  20.4  21.6  22.7  21.4  86.1
[2,]  45.4  28.3  25.4  36.1 135.2
[3,]  13.5  19.2  33.9  24.5  91.1
[4,]  20.7  30.9  18.1  18.0  87.7
[5,] 100.0 100.0 100.1 100.0 400.1
```

Now this table can be subjected to standard Chi-squared test:

```
> chisq.test(mytable)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  mytable
X-squared = 1422.7, df = 9, p-value < 0.00000000000000022
```